# Python, when to use ctypes.byref to pass as reference

Tags: python, c, dll, ctypes

I've loaded a function from a third party DLL. I've been successful accessing the function which is the entry point for the library via `ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary`. The function has 30 parameters including many two dimensional arrays. The function prototype specifies that the parameters be passed by reference in most cases. When I make the function call I'm getting a return code that indicates that there is a problem with an internal variable, which makes me think I've passed the wrong pointers. (It's vague.) My question is, under what circumstances should I use `ctypes.byref` to pass as a reference.  For example, lets say I have the following:

```
double_matrix = (ctypes.c_double * 100) * 100
my_array = double_matrix()
```

Should I pass my_array or ctypes.byref(my_array)?

```
my_string = ctypes.create_string_buffer("Hello world!")
```

What about an object created using types.create_string_buffer()? Should I pass my_string or ctypes.byref(my_string) if passing by reference is required?

Edit:

I don't have the code for the DLL.

Function prototype looks basically like this except there are about 5 or 6 of each type.

int process(char *input, int indicator, double (*dmatrix)[100][100], int (*groups)[100]);

Thanks

Comment: Woha, 30 parameters... If the code is yours, have you considered using an object/struct to logically cluster parameters before passing them?

Comment: Can you show us the C prototype for the function, instead of trying to describe it in English? (Or, even better, show us a stripped-down version that doesn't take 30 parameters…)

Comment: I hope that is a good enough description of the function.

Comment: You are going to need to ask a specific question about one specific parameter. You need to describe the exact semantics of the parameter.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to rework this question.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if your prototype looks like this:

```
int process(char *input, int indicator, double (*dmatrix)[100][100], int (*groups)[100]);
```

then one can generally assume its worth trying the following

Pass the parameters as follows:
   input by reference
   indicator by value
   dmatrix by reference
   groups by reference

Generally speaking assuming  the prototype was a c function and given you are referring to ctypes for python; the process function is expecting you to pass an address reference for the following parameters:  input, dmatrix, and groups.
The indicator variable on the other hand is passed as a direct value.
When a parameter is passed by reference it generally means the receiving function can change the value and whatever changes are made, the caller will be able to analyze the changes directly (as they both are sharing the same particular address space).

If I had to pass 30 parameters over and over, I'd come up with a bridge function to pack them all into a structure fitting the structure of the target parameter list of the function and then simply call the function. then unpack the results (if any) on the way out of the bridge function.

of course this is a guess to some degree, so some of this is a trial by fire...